# Apply a Row major Order for a set of 3D data

Tags: python

Well I am stuck on a problem, where I need to write a set of data file in row major order. The data are 3D concentration points so to say in x, y and z and they are all computed into:
Pac = [Pac[0], Pac[1], Pac[2]]

So I tried to do the following To read these data in row major order:

```
fp = open('pac_data.dat' , 'w')
for iz in range(pac.shape[2]):
    for iy in range(pac.shape[1]):
        for ix in range(pac.shape[0]):
            fp.write(str(pac[ix,iy,iz])+'\t')
        fp.write("\n")
    fp.write("\n")
fp.close()
```

Obviousely from the data result that this is not the answer.
Any help Would be Appreciated

Comment: Could you give a (small) example of 1) your input array (i.e., real data, not the `Pac = [Pac[0], Pac[1], Pac[2]]` you wrote; that's even confusingly recursive); 2) your actual output, and 3) your expected output?
That should help showing us where you want to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what stated above works... if you have data in x, y, and z this works if one wants to arrange the data in row major order